# How can I switch between two ui:compositions in a Facelets file?

Tags: jsf, facelets

In a JSF xhtml file, I would like to be able to choose between two different ui:compositions based on some flag. This is illustrated below using a fictional `magic:if` tag. How can I do this? In other words, what real tag can I use in place of `magic:if`?

```
<magic:if test="showOption1">
  <ui:composition template="/option1.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="header">Foo</ui:define>
  </ui:composition>
</magic:if>

<magic:if test="!showOption1">
  <ui:composition template="/option2.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="header">Foo</ui:define>
  </ui:composition>
</magic:if>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In other words, what real tag can I use in place of magic:if?

There's none. The `<ui:composition>` is the root element. Nothing can end up higher.

You have 2 options:

1. Do the switch in `template` attribute itself.

   ```
   <ui:composition template="/option#{showOption1 ? 1 : 2}.xhtml">
       <ui:define name="header">Foo</ui:define>
   </ui:composition>
   ```
2. Use `<ui:decorate>` inside `<ui:composition>` instead, this one can be wrapped in a `<c:if>`.

   ```
   <ui:composition template="/options.xhtml">
       <c:if test="#{showOption1}">
           <ui:decorate template="/option1.xhtml">
               <ui:define name="header">Foo</ui:define>
           </ui:decorate>
       </c:if>
       <c:if test="#{not showOption1}">
           <ui:decorate template="/option2.xhtml">
               <ui:define name="header">Foo</ui:define>
           </ui:decorate>
       </c:if>
   </ui:composition>
   ```

Comment: The approach of using `ui:decorate` inside of `c:if` worked for me. Thanks! That made me realize that I could also just use `ui:include` wrapped in `c:if`, which is what I ended up doing.

Comment: `<ui:include>` doesn't support `<ui:define>`, so that must have been a very different composition.